# Elasticsearch: how to add language analyser on a field?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, kibana

I have an index with french words. I want to apply an analyser on index properties. Let's say I have a `title` property and I want to consider it as a "french property". I tried this (in kibana):

```
PUT thing/_mappings/thing
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "french",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it results in:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [title] has different [analyzer]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [title] has different [analyzer]]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I don't understand why I have this error. If I display mapping (`GET thing/_mappings`), it contains no existing analyzer (unless I misunderstood something):

```
 // ...
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**How can I consider my `title` property as a french property?** (source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html)

Comment: Do you have another index with a type named `thing`?

Comment: @Val Thank you for your answer. I'm pretty new to elasticsearch, is there a way to check what you asked for?

Comment: Actually you're simply not allowed to change the analyzer of the `title` field, which is `standard` by default if not specified. You need to delete your index and change your mapping properly

Comment: Ok, thanks! So, I have to rebuild all? (so dropping the index, then repost 1G data?) If so, feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not allowed to change the analyzer of the `title` field, which is `standard` by default if not specified when creating the field.

You need to delete your index, change your mapping to fit your needs and then reindex your data.

Another solution would be to add another sub-field to the `title` field with the proper analyzer:

```
PUT thing/_mappings/thing
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "french": {                 <--- add this
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "french"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After running this, you don't need to reupload all your 1GB data, but simply call

```
POST thing/_update_by_query
```

in order to pick up the new sub-field.

The only drawback of this second approach is that you end up with more analyzed data than needed if you don't need the `title` field with the `standard` analyzer. Up to you.